# CMS for Managing Quizzes

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

We're into eLearning and have developed a number of quizzes for various courses.

Now we are looking for a CMS/system which could do something like this -

- Allow us to create accounts for
  clients. Once an account is created
  and quizzes are in place rest should
  be driven by our clients.
- Clients should be able to choose how many employees/students they wish to enroll for a particular quiz.
- Client
  should be able to choose a fixed
  number of questions from a set of
  questions already in the quiz,
  duration and should be able to set
  pass rates for their
  employees/students.
- As soon as their
  employees/student completes an exam,
  client should get an email with
  pass/fail rate.

Wondering if there is any CMS which has functionality near to what I discussed above?

Comment: :( Well, I found a tag "CMS" here. In case others too feel the same - I am sorry - mods please transfer it. With so many SE siblings popping up every day, at times it is confusing to decide where should we post a question. May be I'll go ahead and vote for new community for CMS cms.se.com :)

Comment: I've edited your question (so it can be migrated) and flagged it for migration. Webmasters SE is a perfect site for this.

Comment: Moodle? Schools use it for that, and other features. it's a bit heavy.

Comment: @DKuntz2 - Thanks. So Moodle can do ALL what I have described above?

Comment: Just as a cross-reference, there's a similar [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393671/php-quiz-management-software-igivetest-free-replacement).

Comment: @Ankur: So far as I know (I've only used it from the student end). I know that you can make accounts for users, specify classes that their in, give certain classes certain quizzes (with multiple choice, short/long answer, check boxes, ect). I don't know about the pass/fail rates, but I would assume so. I also don't know about the emailing of the rate afterwards, but I would assume you could modify Moodle to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

hey moodle is one good cms which will help you.
and if you want to have everything what you want,then go and make a simple CMS for yourself in PHP or any other web develpment language.

Comment: I personally know Moodle Quizes, but I'm interested to know if there are Quizz-only scripts out there. For other types of simple quizes installing and configuring Moodle is just to much.

Comment: Do you mean Later on fine-tuning and additional configuring ? As for what is installing, using the Moodle Bitnami installer (at bitnami.org) does seem easy to me.

Comment: +1 @Osvaldo There are various modules for Drupal and Joomla that would let you build this, but it would be a bit like using a screwdriver as a hammer.